# Create custom list from main list in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, listobject

I have a list object like below

```
[{a:"0"},{a:"1"},....{a:"39"}]
```

I want to have a list like the one below.I need a result like the below.

```
{
  "list1":[{a:"0"},{a:"1"},{a:"2"},{a:"3"}],
  "list2":[{a:"4"},{a:"5"},{a:"6"},{a:"7"}],
  .
  .
  .
  "list10":[{a:"36"},{a:"37"},{a:"38"},{a:"39"}],
}
```

Thanks for help me.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want an object as your output and not an array? Since your object seems to be using sequential keys it looks like an array might be better suited (which then you can use a [chunking method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8495687/5648954))

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @SaeedAs You have to upvote the answer if it's helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using `slice()` data...

```js
const arr = [{a:"0"},{a:"1"},{a:"2"},{a:"3"},{a:"4"},{a:"5"},{a:"6"},{a:"7"}];

const arr2 = [];

var i,j;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 4) {
    arr2.push(arr.slice(i, i + 4));
}
    
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code:

```js
const items = [{a: "0"}, {a: "1"}, {a: "2"}, {a: "3"}, {a: "4"}, {a: "5"}, {a: "6"}, {a: "7"}, {a:"8"}, {a:"9"}, {a:"10"}];
let newItems = {};
let i = 1;
while(items.length){
    newItems[`list${i}`] = items.splice(0,4);
    i++;
}
console.log(newItems)
```

If you want too kep the `items` immutable you can copy it into another array before `while` loop, like this `const copyItems = [...items]` and using `copyItems` in `while`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `reduce` to achieve this

```js
const items = [{ a: "0" }, { a: "1" }, { a: "2" }, { a: "3" }, { a: "4" }, { a: "5" }, { a: "6" }, { a: "7" }];
items.reduce((accum, curr, index) => {
  const key = `list${1 + Math.floor(index / 4)}`;
  accum[key] = accum[key] || [];
  accum[key].push(curr);
  return accum;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might be what you're looking for. This will split the big array into smaller ones and store each array with a size of 4 in the arrayOfArrays.

```
var bigarray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];
var size = 4; var arrayOfArrays = [];
for (var i=0; i<bigarray.length; i+=size) {
  arrayOfArrays.push(bigarray.slice(i,i+size));
}
console.log(arrayOfArrays); // [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{a:"0"},{a:"1"},{a:"2"},{a:"3"}, {a:"4"},{a:"5"},{a:"6"},{a:"7"},{a:"8"},{a:"9"}]

const sliceData = (data, size) => {
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i += size){
       result.push(data.slice(i, i + size));
   }
  return result;
}

console.log(sliceData(data, 4));
```

result

```
[
  [ { a: '0' }, { a: '1' }, { a: '2' }, { a: '3' } ],
  [ { a: '4' }, { a: '5' }, { a: '6' }, { a: '7' } ],
  [ { a: '8' }, { a: '9' } ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Lodash, if you don't mind**

Use *_.chunk* to split array into groups the length of size.

```
import _ from 'lodash';

data = [{a:"0"},{a:"1"},{a:"2"},{a:"3"}, {a:"4"},{a:"5"},{a:"6"},{a:"7"},{a:"8"},{a:"9"}];
const size = 4;
const result = _.chunk(data, size)
   .reduce((acc, item, index) => ({ ...acc, [`list${index + 1}`]: item }), {});

console.log(result);
//{list1: Array(4), list2: Array(4), list3: Array(2)}
```